# The Cula-suññata Sutta - Pali Canon and emptiness

Tags: sutras, sunyata

**I've closed the question. No need to answer**

It's a sore and sensitive subject, emptiness.

The Cula-suññata Sutta: The Lesser Discourse on Emptiness.

What else is there in the Pali canon that has a direct mentioning of these types of emptiness?

My teacher had mentioned that Mahayana goes into emptiness with quite some depth. (There's something really wrong with that sentence!)

Can you provide any Mahayana teachings that can help me unpack the types of emptiness mentioned in the Cula-suññata?

Comment: I've realised that I'm trying to bite a tomato seed with this one. I'll just try to figure this out for myself such has been the process thus far.

Comment: If you really want to experience what the Mahayana school teaches about emptiness, just sit down on the cushion and see for yourself.  It's much easier than chasing footnotes!

Comment: @ 000 - I had figured that this would be so. How can one put this into a concept which is roughly what I was seeking. I would only fall back into mental abstractions. I'll have to figure this out for myself. ;-)

Comment: A nice summary of Pali Canon's view on emptiness can be found in a book "The Concept of Emptiness in Pali Literature" available on [Samana Johan's community site](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=tpmod;dl=item10).

Comment: @ Andrei - it's an interesting read. ;-)

Comment: Further to 000's comment I'd suggest starting with Nagarjuna.